# Why am I still getting spam email and what more can I do to stop it?

Tags: email, email-server

I've set up SpamAssassin on my server

I've configured my dmarc, DKIM and spf records in my domain's DNS which wasn't easy to figure out how to do correctly but for a while after I'd done this the spam stopped but now its back again.

Here's my dmarc, DKIM and SPF records all as TXT records on the DNS (I changed actual values so these don't reflect *actual* data on my domain).

dmarc:

> v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:*email*; ruf=mailto:*email*; aspf=r; adkim=r

DKIM:

> v=DKIM1; k=skh; p=MIIBIkug876GKgut785ukutioogiyry47gmhMHFyrJKkmsOyyK+J

spf:

> v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:*mail server ip* -all

What more can I do to stop the spam?

Comment: None of these measures are meant to prevent spam sent to you. They all are meant to allow others to detect spam that has been sent in your name.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I will save that link and look at it when I get back to the office. Thanks